# localhost working fine but phpmyadmin is not

Tags: php, http, phpmyadmin, apache2, wamp

I have installed Wamp Server 2.4. Installation goes fine. I am able to log into the the localhost. Everything works fine (includes the sqlbuddy and webgrind), except the phpmyadmin page. Can you please help me out with what might be causing this problem. I am attaching the apache access log here:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2013:17:20:43 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2013:17:20:43 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209

When I try to log into the phpmyadmin page, it displays the HTTP 500 internal server error. Tried reinstalling already.
Same problem persists with XAMPP. Tried that too.

Comment: Are you sure there is a alias for phpMyAdmin? You can check as following: right click WAMP icon > Apache > Alias directories. It should be listed there.

Comment: If you click 'Edit alias', can you check the alias?

Comment: Yes, a phpmyadmin.conf file opens.

Comment: Try downloading latest version of phpMyAdmin from its official website and try using it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start MySQL service? I'm using XAMPP so I don't know how it is done in WAMP, but in XAMPP I have to go to XAMPP Control Panel and press Start next to MySQL.